# Nothing happening when running code sas

Tags: sas

Does anyone else have this problem? Basically, sometimes when I write a macro and run the code, nothing happens. The log just writes the code you tried to execute in black but it's like SAS is disabled and you have to turn off SAS and turn it back on before it runs properly again. Is there a way around this without having to turn off and on sas.

this is my code:

```
dm 'clear log';                                                                                                                                                                
dm 'clear output';                                                                                                                                                             
dm 'odsresults: clear';                                                                                                                                                        
libname projet 'C:\Users\MJ-INFO\Desktop\Projet scoring1' ;                                                                                                                    
/*Extrcation de la base d'etude et creation d'une copie*/                                                                                                                      
data Examen ;                                                                                                                                                                  
set projet.base_resiliation_proj ;                                                                                                                                             
run;                                                                                                                                                                           

/*Contenu de la base*/                                                                                                                                                         
proc contents data=Examen;                                                                                                                                                     
run;                                                                                                                                                                           
/*Corespondance entre les formats et les variables */                                                                                                                          

proc format ;                                                                                                                                                                  
value $sexe                                                                                                                                                                    
"1"="homme"                                                                                                                                                                    
"2"="femme";                                                                                                                                                                   
run;                                                                                                                                                                           
/*Applicatation des formats*/                                                                                                                                                  
data Examen;                                                                                                                                                                   
set projet.base_resiliation_proj ;                                                                                                                                             
format sexe $sexe.;                                                                                                                                                            
run ;                                                                                                                                                                          

/*Nous avons 53892 observations et 8 variables dans notre base*/                                                                                                               

/*Definition de la variable à expliquer *                                                                                                                                      
%let var_cible=RESIL;                                                                                                                                                          

/*Definition des variables explicatives */                                                                                                                                     
%let var_quali=formule sexe;                                                                                                                                                   
%let var_quanti=anc_client anc_cont cotisation id nb_cont;                                                                                                                     
/*Vue sur la variable cible*/                                                                                                                                                  
proc freq data=Examen;                                                                                                                                                         
table &var_cible;                                                                                                                                                              
run;                                                                                                                                                                           
/*14.42 des contrats sont des fragiles*/                                                                                                                                       
/*Exploration des variables candidates  de la base*/                                                                                                                           
proc freq data=Examen;                                                                                                                                                         
table &var_quali;                                                                                                                                                              
run;                                                                                                                                                                           

proc means data=Examen min max mean median nmiss;                                                                                                                              
var &var_quanti;                                                                                                                                                               
run;                                                                                                                                                                           

/*Traitement des valeurs manquantes/aberrantes*/                                                                                                                               
data Examen;                                                                                                                                                                   
set Examen;                                                                                                                                                                    
if cotisation=-1 then delete;                                                                                                                                                  
if cotisation='.' then delete;                                                                                                                                                 
if nb_cont=99999 then delete;                                                                                                                                                  
run;                                                                                                                                                                           

/*II.Preparation des donnees*/                                                                                                                                                 
/*Etude des liaisons entre variables qualitatives et variable cible */                                                                                                         
/*Variables qualitatives : test de Khi-2 & v de Cramer*/                                                                                                                       
%macro quali(table,var,cible,mod);                                                                                                                                             
/*Representation en terme d'effectif*/                                                                                                                                         
proc gchart data=&table;                                                                                                                                                       
vbar3d &var. / sumvar=&cible discrete;                                                                                                                                         
title "Effectifs de la variable &var";                                                                                                                                         
run;                                                                                                                                                                           
/*Taux de contrat à risque*                                                                                                                                                    
proc freq data=&table;                                                                                                                                                         
table &var.*&cible / chisq outpct out=pct;                                                                                                                                     
run;                                                                                                                                                                           
proc gchart data=pct (where=(&cible=&mod));                                                                                                                                    
vbar3d &var. / sumvar=pct_row discrete;                                                                                                                                        
title "Taux de contrats à risque de la variable &var";                                                                                                                         
run;                                                                                                                                                                           
quit;                                                                                                                                                                          
title;                                                                                                                                                                         
%mend;                                                                                                                                                                         
%quali(Examen,sexe,&var_cible,1);
```

Sas show me black execute from running this code:

```
/*II.Preparation des donnees*/                                                                                                                                                 
/*Etude des liaisons entre variables qualitatives et variable cible */                                                                                                         
/*Variables qualitatives : test de Khi-2 & v de Cramer*/                                                                                                                       
%macro quali(table,var,cible,mod);                                                                                                                                             
/*Representation en terme d'effectif*/                                                                                                                                         
proc gchart data=&table;                                                                                                                                                       
vbar3d &var. / sumvar=&cible discrete;                                                                                                                                         
title "Effectifs de la variable &var";                                                                                                                                         
run;
```

I didn't understand why I get black execute even my code has no error when I see the log page ??

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code:

```
%macro quali(table,var,cible,mod);                                                                                                                                             
/*Representation en terme d'effectif*/                                                                                                                                         
proc gchart data=&table;                                                                                                                                                       
vbar3d &var. / sumvar=&cible discrete;                                                                                                                                         
title "Effectifs de la variable &var";                                                                                                                                         
run;
```

started to define a macro but never finished. There is no %mend statement at the end, so SAS thinks your still sending it macro code to be compiled. If you add a %mend, it should work.

Most common reasons for SAS feeling non responsive in this way are unclosed macro definition, unclosed comment block, and unmatched quotes.  If you google "SAS magic string" you'll find examples of code you can submit to try to recover when you're stuck in this situation.  Stuff like:

```
*';*";*/;%mend;
```

If you're using Enterprise Guide it automatically adds a magic string every time you submit code. This means you're session won't feel hung. But where you have an unclosed macro definition it can make it harder to recognize,because it looks like everything fan fine. But in reality it didn't execute at all. The magic string can end up hiding the problem. I assume SAS studio also adds a magic string, but I haven't checked.

Comment: SAS Studio can be used to run interactively as well as batch so it's different in EG in that respect. Studio does add the magic string, but it doesn't include a %MEND, `&GRAPHTERM; ;*';*";*/;RUN;QUIT;`